# Algorithm to find a ( any) solution that satisfy a set of nonlinear inequalities equations

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-system

I have three variables$(r, \theta)$, determined by the following inequality constraints equations:

$$f_1(r,\theta)=P-p_c(r,\theta)<=0$$
$$f_2(r,\theta)=M_x-m_{cx}(r,\theta)<=0$$
$$f_3(r,\theta)=M_y-m_{cy}(r,\theta)<=0$$
$$-\infty<r<\infty$$
$$0\leq\theta\leq\pi$$

where $P$, $M_x$ and $M_y$ are given constants.

where $p_c(r,\theta)$ , $m_{cx}(r,\theta)$, $m_{cy}(r,\theta)$ are very complicated nonlinear equations.

The partial derivatives for $f_1(r,\theta)$, $f_2(r,\theta)$ and $f_3(r,\theta)$ are all available, and these functions are continuous over the interested region.

I just need to find **one** set of value $(r, \theta)$ that fulfills the above constraints. So this is ***not*** an optimization problem.

Is there any good, fast algorithm (AKA search methods) that can do so?

I will have to implement it in a computer, so any open source library in any language is also welcome.

Comment: Why do you say it's not an optimization problem? Optimization includes "feasibility problems", where we are asked to find a point $x$ that belongs to a set $S$. You can reformulate a feasibility problem as "minimize $0$ subject to the constraint that $x \in S$", which is an optimization problem. Then use any optimization algorithm capable of solving the optimization problem.

Comment: @littleO, I can, but the problem is that an optimization problem will not stop looking until you hit an extremum, but in my case, I don't need an extremum; just any pair that satisfies the constraint will do

Comment: An optimization algorithm will not stop looking until it finds a *minimizer*, and any point $x$ that satisfies the constraint $x \in S$ is indeed a minimizer for the problem "minimize $0$ subject to the constraint that $x \in S$".

Comment: @littleO, I know. I would say that formulating the problem as optimization problem may not be efficient for me ( of course I can do that), it might be very restrictive and introduce unnecessary performance penalty

Answer (score 0):

If $e_x , e_y \ge 0$, your three inequalities all give lower bounds on $P$ depending on $r$ and $\theta$.  Then it's easy: take any $r$ and $\theta$, and compute the lower bounds on $P$.

If at least one of $e_x$ and $e_y$ is negative, you have both upper and lower bounds, and you need to search $(r,\theta)$ space for some point where the lower bounds are less than or equal to the upper bounds.  There are various search strategies you can use.  Assuming $p_c$, $m_{cx}$ and $m_{cy}$ are continuous, if there is a point where the lower bounds are strictly less than the upper bounds you are guaranteed to find it if you search a dense sequence in $(r,\theta)$ space.

EDIT: For the edited question, again you have to search $(r,\theta)$ space.  Again, it can be done by searching a dense sequence if the functions are continuous and there is some point where the inequalities are all satisfied strictly.

Especially if partial derivatives are available, you might try some local search methods rather than just following a predetermined sequence.

Comment: I just realized that my inequalities have the wrong sign ( should be $<=0$ instead of the other way round). Question fixed now, your answer still valid?

Comment: I read my question and I found it extremely wrong. Now I have edited it. Actually I just need to determine the $(r, \theta)$ pair ( and not $(P,r, \theta)$ as originally claimed). I think this is much harder than solving the original question

Comment: The partial derivatives are available, but I am not familiar with such local search methods, can recommend some?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on the complicated functions (such as boundedness of the derivatives, Lipschitz condition, heuristic knowledge...), I am afraid there is no better way than systematic sampling of the domain, as far as you can and with steps as small as you can.

In any case, you need at least some knowledge on the scale of the variations. Oversampling will take ages and undersampling will miss the solutions.

Comment: Scale of the variations.. is it not that the bounded range for $r$ and $\theta$ good enough?

Comment: @Graviton: Bandwidth would be a more appropriate term, but I didn't want to be technical. Take that informally. By the way, you said $r$ unbounded.

Comment: Do you have any literature ( or even better, code library) that does this?

Comment: @Graviton: can't you write a double loop ?

Comment: Of course I can, but won't that be terribly inefficient? Is there no other better algorithm that can search faster?

Comment: @Graviton: please read and understand my answer.